# triggering multiple timed JavaScript functions onload

Tags: javascript, delay, onload

I've got a beautifully cheesy fireworks animation that I trigger onload using this code

```
<body onload="createFirework(50,1500,15,1,1,100,50,50,false,false); ">
```

I want to trigger 3 instances of the fireworks 1 second apart onload, however I don't know the best method to achieve this.

Many thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a separate function where you will call createFirework 3 times.
So you can play with params for each firework

```
<script>
  function createMyFirework(){
    createFirework(50,1500,15,1,1,100,50,50,false,false);
    createFirework(50,1500,15,1,1,100,50,50,false,false);
    createFirework(50,1500,15,1,1,100,50,50,false,false);
  }
</script>

<body onload="createMyFirework(); ">
```

Comment: Thanks - works fine, using settimeout I've implemented the delay:            <script>
    function createMyFirework(){
    createFirework(50,1500,15,1,1,100,50,50,false,false);
    setTimeout("createFirework(50,1500,15,1,1,100,50,50,false,false);",1000);  
    setTimeout("createFirework(50,1500,15,1,1,100,50,50,false,false);",2000);
    
  }
</script>